Re-configuration of rsyslog
Probably a bit of an "off-kilter" question, but I want to conduct some experiments with rsyslog. I'd like to configure it to log nothing except the messages that I send with logger.
This is for a Raspberry Pi Lite (aka "headless") machine running "Bookworm". It has systemd installed, and already generates massive amounts of logs with journalctl. I don't need more logfiles; I just want something that I can use exclusively for my purposes. IOW, I want to stop rsyslog from logging anything except what I specifically request using logger.
I installed rsyslog using apt, quickly skimmed the man page, and then modified /etc/rsyslog.conf. Following is what I've got left in rsyslog.conf; hopefully you can tell what I changed as I inserted a tab between the # & the config statement:
# /etc/rsyslog.conf configuration file for rsyslog

#### MODULES ####
module(load="imuxsock") # provides support for local system logging
#     module(load="imklog")   # provides kernel logging support
#module(load="immark")  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# provides UDP syslog reception
#module(load="imudp")
#input(type="imudp" port="514")

# provides TCP syslog reception
#module(load="imtcp")
#input(type="imtcp" port="514")

#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
$FileOwner root
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022

# Where to place spool and state files
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
#     $IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

#### RULES ####
# Log anything besides private authentication messages to a single log file
#     *.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
user.*            -/var/log/syslog
:omusrmsg:root    -/var/log/syslog

# Log commonly used facilities to their own log file
#     auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
#     cron.*                          -/var/log/cron.log
#     kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
#     mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log
#     user.*                          -/var/log/user.log

*.emerg                         :omusrmsg:*

I removed everything from /var/log/syslog, and left rsyslog running for a while.  I've checked /var/log/syslog earlier, and there was nothing there except for a couple of logger messages I sent via a regular user crontab job, and a root crontab job.
Does this configuration look like it will do what I want; i.e. log only what I send via logger, and not interfere/disrupt journalctl? Am I setting myself up for a disaster?

welcome, Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User
